# Proving an operation $*$ is associative.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

We are given that $*$ is an operation on a two-element set $\{e,a\}$ and that $e$ is an identity element for $*$.

We want to prove that $*$ is associative.

We know $a*e = e*a$ because $e$ is an identity element.

$a = a$

$a*(e*a) = a*(e*a)$

$a*e*a = a*e*a$

$(a*e)*a = a*(e*a)$, since $e$ is an identity element.

So $*$ is associative.

Am I doing things out of order, am I assuming the conclusion anywhere? Let me know where I went wrong if anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: You have to prove $x*(y*z)=(x*y)*z$ for all options of $x,y,z$. Luckily there are only $8$ options.

Answer (score 1):

you just have to prove $x(yz)=(xy)z$ for all $a,b,c\in \{e,a\}$.

Case $1$: $a*a=e$.

If the triple $(x,y,z)$ is $(e,e,e)$ then $(e*e)*e=e=e*(e*e)$

If the triple $(x,y,z)$ is $(e,e,a)$ then $(e*e)*a=a=e*(e*a)$

If the triple $(x,y,z)$ is $(e,a,e)$ then $(e*a)*e=a=e*(a*e)$

If the triple $(x,y,z)$ is $(e,a,a)$ then $(e*a)*a=e=e*(a*a)$

If the triple $(x,y,z)$ is $(a,e,e)$ then $(a*e)*e=a=a*(e*e)$

If the triple $(x,y,z)$ is $(a,e,a)$ then $(a*e)*a=e=a*(e*a)$

If the triple $(x,y,z)$ is $(a,a,e)$ then $(a*a)*e=e=a*(a*e)$

If the triple $(x,y,z)$ is $(a,a,a)$ then $(a*a)*a=a=a*(a*a)$

Case $2$: $a*a=a$

If the triple $(x,y,z)$ is $(e,e,e)$ then $(e*e)*e=e=e*(e*e)$

If the triple $(x,y,z)$ is $(e,e,a)$ then $(e*e)*a=a=e*(e*a)$

If the triple $(x,y,z)$ is $(e,a,e)$ then $(e*a)*e=a=e*(a*e)$

If the triple $(x,y,z)$ is $(e,a,a)$ then $(e*a)*a=a=e*(a*a)$

If the triple $(x,y,z)$ is $(a,e,e)$ then $(a*e)*e=a=a*(e*e)$

If the triple $(x,y,z)$ is $(a,e,a)$ then $(a*e)*a=a=a*(e*a)$

If the triple $(x,y,z)$ is $(a,a,e)$ then $(a*a)*e=a=a*(a*e)$

If the triple $(x,y,z)$ is $(a,a,a)$ then $(a*a)*a=a=a*(a*a)$

Comment: Oh ok. I was confused when I looked at the definition of associative and saw that there were $x,y,z$ and my set has only two, but it makes sense that they can repeat.

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove $x*(y*z) =(x*y)*z$ for any possible values of x,y,z.  Technically there are $2^3= 8$ possible values to test but we can do some short cuts.

If $x=e$ then $e*(y*z)=y*z=(y)*z=(e*y)*z $. So that takes care of 4 cases.

similarly if $y=e $ we have $x*(e*z)=x*z=(x*e)*z $ and if $z=e $ we have $x*(y*e)=x*y=(x*y)*e $. That takes care of 7 cases.

The only case left is $x=y=z=a $.

But we haven't been told what $a*a $.  There are two options.  $a*a=a$ (not a group BTW) or $a*a=e $

If $a*a=a $ we have $a*(a*a)=a*(a) = a*a =(a)*a=(a*a)*a $.

If $a*a=e $ then $a*(a*a)=a*e=a=e*a=(a*a)*a $

That's all the possibilities.  $x*(y*z)=(x*y)*z$ no matter what x,y,z equals or what $a*a$ equals.